# Embedding Contour using iframe to filter data from workshop

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

How to filter contour dashboard which is embedded using iframe ? I know we need to modify contour link to filter but don't know how to do that exactly.

I expect to filter contour dashboard when I apply certain filters on workshop

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a Contour Dashboard [parameterized](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/contour/analysis-parameterize/), you can generate a URL to pass values of parameters in the "parameter" tab, in Contour.

[image]

You can then use this URL in Workshop, and generate/inject the value of the parameters like a string.

Note that you can't pass data (like rows or Objects) from Workshop to Contour. Contour operates on [datasets](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/data-integration/datasets/) and Workshop on [Objects](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/object-link-types/object-types-overview/).

You should look into [Quiver](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/overview/) in order to achieve what you seem to want to achieve: allow users to continue their analysis from Workshop, with the full flexibility of a dedicated analytics tool, but bootstrapped from Workshop.
Specifically, you are looking for [Quiver Embedded in Workshop](https://www.palantir.com/docs/foundry/quiver/dashboards-workshop/) where variables containing Objects, etc. can be shared bi-directionally (Quiver => Workshop and Workshop => Quiver).